# Modify key values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can I properly format or update a `date_created` value inside an array so after I will have the same array but with some modified values in it ?

I want to format a `date_created` values with this function `date("D, d F Y, H:i:s", strtotime($date_created));`

Here is the result of dumped array - `var_dump($query)`:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Title 2' (length=55)
      'date_created' => string '2011-03-09 08:04:14' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Title 2' (length=57)
      'date_created' => string '2011-08-14 18:34:04' (length=19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you'll have to do is iterate over the array, change the values and replace the sub array with the original in the same index.

```
foreach($query as $key => $subArray){
  $subArray['date_created'] = date("D, d F Y, H:i:s", strtotime($subArray['date_created']));
  $query[$key] = $subArray['date_created'];
}
```

Comment: And one question - what's wrong with my question ? Why I get minus ?

Comment: Well I'm not the voter so I can't say for sure why... But perhaps it is because this is a relatively simple task - to iterate over an array, and you did not show what you have tried already to resolve this...  People want to know that you put some effort into your post...

Comment: Oh I see now, I'am sorry, but my english is at very poor level and I didn't know how to explain it. If I ever know the meaning of "iterate" before, I think it will be easier to find the answer. Thanks a lot again Lix.

Comment: No problem! happy to help!  Don't feel bad about it, its only the opinion of one person :)